# Conditionally update argument to function in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to conditionally update an argument to a function:

```rust
struct A {
    foo: i32,
    bar: i32,
}

impl A {
    fn foobar<'a>(&'a self) {
        let a;
        if true { // something more complex obviously
            let x = A {
                foo: self.foo,
                bar: self.bar,
            };
            a = &x;
        } else {
            a = self;
        }
        
        println!("{} {}", a.foo, a.bar);
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=27fcba42d135da6282bd000fd8e3db5d

Here, the function `foobar` receives an argument of type `&A`. Depending on some condition I want to replace this argument with another value of type `&A`.

I do understand why the above code results in the error `'x' does not live long enough`. My question is whether there is a pattern to conditionally update the value of the argument `a` without requiring it to be mutable? Is there maybe a way to forcefully extend the lifetime of `x`?

Comment: really just call your function in both branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `if` condition, you give to `a` a reference to `x`, which will be destroyed just after. Then `a` will hold a reference to a destroyed object.

You can fix it by declaring the `x` variable before the condition:

```
struct A {
    foo: i32,
    bar: i32,
}

impl A {
    fn foobar<'a>(&'a self) {
        let a;
        let x;
        if true { // something more complex obviously
            x = A {
                foo: self.foo,
                bar: self.bar,
            };
            a = &x;
        } else {
            a = self;
        }

        println!("{} {}", a.foo, a.bar);
    }
}
```

You can also simplify your code, by removing the lifetimes and using the pattern `let a = if ... {} else {};` :

```
    fn foobar(&self) {
        let x;
        let a = if true { // something more complex obviously
            x = A {
                foo: self.foo,
                bar: self.bar,
            };
            &x
        } else {
            self
        };

        println!("{} {}", a.foo, a.bar);
    }
```

Comment: notice that this will add runtime overhead and in my opinion is ugly code.